# How to get all location list from foursquare api?

Tags: foursquare

I have gone through the foursquare api, But I can't find what I want.

I need to get all the places name, city name, country name with latitude & longitude.

Is there any specific api url for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if any company would let you download **all** of their data from any domain.

Answer (score 3):

This is achievable if you can build a good deamon and let it work 24 hours with a good algorithm with good error handling.

If you have the time, you could do multi-venue-explore (like millions) requests to a big list of longitudes and latitudes to get everything.
You will be limited with 5000 userless requests/hour and will need to store the results in a database as it comes in, to avoid duplicates you can check against venue_id before storing any new result.

You will also be limited with almost 50 results per query.

If you can imagine how this would go:
1- You would start to query a point with 5 KM radius, this query might return 0 results or 30 results or even 4000 results, depending on how many venues are registered in that radius.
2- if none, you can start the new point query after the 5 KM, if it returns more the full 50 venues set, then you probably would query within the 5 KM, to get more results, maybe in the next meter or next K metetrs.

Use:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there isn't an API that returns every venue. If you're looking to find venues that match certain parameters, such as the best match venues at a given location, in a given category, or based on a given search query we have both a [search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) and [explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) endpoint that can help.

However, a complete list API is not available both because the amount of data it sent back would be far too large to send over the internet and because there don't seem to be any legitimate uses for one that don't violate our [Terms](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues#rules), which pretty clearly ban storing location data for long periods or for one's own location database.